# LEFT JOIN in Dynamics AX View

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dataview, aot

Does anyone know how to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN in a Dynamics AX View from the AOT (not a programmatically-created query).

Can't seem to find a way to do anything other than an INNER JOIN, and the documentation seems to indicate it isn't possible.

This seems to be a huge weakness, so I figure if they don't support it, there is a recommended way to accomplish the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into a standard [Query](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qaG5s.png)?

Comment: We are using this for a very specific function that unfortunately requires a View.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to create *Query* and then set the `Query` property of the *View* to that query.

On query data sources you can select `JoinMode`:

- `InnerJoin` - creates INNER or CROSS JOIN
- `OuterJoin` - creates LEFT JOIN
- `ExistsJoin` - creates WHERE EXISTS (...)
- `NotExistsJoin` - creates WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

See: [Create a View Based on a Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa558501.aspx)

Comment: In addition to, using Query is always a best practice, and a must in case you need to add more than one DS under another DS (since this a limitation in the view)...
and then you can easily use that query it in a view or a form as a DS.